# Execute project java-ee with maven on eclipse gives error connection

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I get this error when I try to execute a maven install. I use Eclipse for that little project on Java EE.

I read that maybe a proxy is the cause of the problem. I already added my proxy (I'm not sure of it id) in the file `settings.xml`.

Anyone knows how to correct this problem?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven- install-  
plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project socle: Execution default-
install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install 
failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of   
its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at  
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> 
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Failed to read artifact 
descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Could not transfer 
artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.0.5 from/to ftven-nexus.repo 
(http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public): Connect 
 to 46.193.65.252:57825 [/46.193.65.252] failed: Connection timed out:  
 connect -> [Help 1]

 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute
```

Here's the full log:

```
    [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\bou\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\3.0.5\plexus-utils-3.0.5.pom.lastUpdated
    [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public
    [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public with username=reader, password=*** via 46.193.65.252:57825 with username=bou, password=***
    [INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-digest/1.0/plexus-digest-1.0.pom
    [DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\bou\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-digest\1.0\plexus-digest-1.0.pom.lastUpdated
    [DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=32, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=14, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=32, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=43100, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=48}
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] socle parent ....................................... FAILURE [ 43.352 s]
    [INFO] socle_Commun ....................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] socle_Donnee ....................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] socle_Contrainte ................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] socle_Repository ................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] socle_Stub_Test .................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] socle_Service ...................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] socle_Presentation ................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] socle_Infrastructure ............................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 43.508 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-07T21:16:52+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project socle: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.0.5 from/to ftven-nexus.repo (http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public): Connect to 46.193.65.252:57825 [/46.193.65.252] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project socle: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:104)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:204)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:329)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:229)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:100)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:192)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.0.5 from/to ftven-nexus.repo (http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public): Connect to 46.193.65.252:57825 [/46.193.65.252] failed: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.0.5 from/to ftven-nexus.repo (http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public): Connect to 46.193.65.252:57825 [/46.193.65.252] failed: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connect to 46.193.65.252:57825 [/46.193.65.252] failed: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1085)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:977)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 46.193.65.252:57825 [/46.193.65.252] failed: Connection timed out: connect
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:371)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:848)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1000)
        ... 50 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
        ... 60 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you nexus isn't available. Have you tried to access `http://nexus.mobilite.build.indus.ftven.net/content/groups/public` in a browser? Probably your nexus is down or the proxy is misconfigured.

If its a proxy issue, check your proxy settings in `settings.xml`. See here for further information: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html